# C++ (g++) , Codelite, Ubuntu, Mysql - все вместе :)

Tags: компилятор, c++, mysql

Возникла задача написать некоторый код, который будет что-то делать с БД Mysql. Сложность в настройке опций для g++.

В данный момент опции такие:

```
g++ -I/usr/include/mysql++ -I/usr/include/mysql
```

Пути верные, но нормально собираться проект не хочет.

> `----------Build Started--------
> /bin/sh -c '"make"  -j 2 -f "MHC_wsp.mk"'
> ----------Building project:[ Myhobby - Debug ]----------
> make[1]: Вход в каталог '/home/kost/.codelite/MHC'
> g++ -c  "/home/kost/.codelite/MHC/main.cpp" -g -I/usr/include/mysql++ -I/usr/include/mysql  -o ./Debug/main.o "-I." "-I." 
> /home/kost/.codelite/MHC/main.cpp:1:19: warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive
> /home/kost/.codelite/MHC/main.cpp:2:19: warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive
> /home/kost/.codelite/MHC/main.cpp:3:20: warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive
> /home/kost/.codelite/MHC/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> /home/kost/.codelite/MHC/main.cpp:63:19: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
> /home/kost/.codelite/MHC/main.cpp:64:17: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
> /home/kost/.codelite/MHC/main.cpp:65:21: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
> /home/kost/.codelite/MHC/main.cpp:66:21: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
> /home/kost/.codelite/MHC/main.cpp:72:56: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
> g++ -o ./Debug/Myhobby ./Debug/main.o  "-L."
> ./Debug/main.o: In function 'mysql_connection_setup(connection_details)':
> /home/kost/.codelite/MHC/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to 'mysql_init'
> /home/kost/.codelite/MHC/main.cpp:27: undefined reference to 'mysql_real_connect'
> /home/kost/.codelite/MHC/main.cpp:28: undefined reference to 'mysql_error'
> ./Debug/main.o: In function 'mysql_perform_query(st_mysql*, char*)':
> /home/kost/.codelite/MHC/main.cpp:41: undefined reference to 'mysql_query'
> /home/kost/.codelite/MHC/main.cpp:43: undefined reference to 'mysql_error'
> /home/kost/.codelite/MHC/main.cpp:47: undefined reference to 'mysql_use_result'
> ./Debug/main.o: In function 'main':
> /home/kost/.codelite/MHC/main.cpp:79: undefined reference to 'mysql_fetch_row'
> /home/kost/.codelite/MHC/main.cpp:83: undefined reference to 'mysql_free_result'
> /home/kost/.codelite/MHC/main.cpp:85: undefined reference to 'mysql_close'
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
> make[1]: *** [Debug/Myhobby] Ошибка 1
> make[1]: Выход из каталога '/home/kost/.codelite/MHC'
> make: *** [All] Ошибка 2
> ----------Build Ended----------
> 9 errors, 8 warnings`

Пока для меня совершенно непонятно почему.

P.S. права на `/usr/include/mysql (mysql++) = 777`
P.P.S. - Собственно, проблема в том, что не видит компилятор ссылки на необходимые объекты :(

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что в хедерах (*.h) находятся только объявления функций, т.е. их интерфейс.
Скомпилированный код этих функций, находится в библиотеке. Поэтому при линковке нужно добавить библиотеку libmysql++, в которой определены недостающие символы. Строка копиляции при линковке будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
g++ -o ./Debug/Myhobby ./Debug/main.o -lmysqlpp
```

Это значит, что компилятор должен прилинковать динамическую библиотеку libmysqlpp.so, котороя располагается либо в одной из директорий указанных явно (-L[имя директории]), либо в дефолтной системной директории с установленными библиотеками (обычно /usr/lib).

**PS**:
Не стоит явно указывать опции -I"/usr/include/...". Компилятор сам ищет includes в том месте, где установленные библиотеки хранят свои хэдеры (обычно это /usr/include). В программме include надо писать примерно так:

```
#include <mysql++/query.h>
```

**PPS**:
Зря у вас на /usr/include/mysql++ права 777 - у обычных юзеров не должно быть прав на изменение этои директории.